# Gerar vários PDFS via Itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que monta pdf's dinamicamente através da biblioteca Itextsharp.

Está funcionando e disponibilizando o download corretamente, porém gostaria de gerar uma quantidade maior de documentos. E esbarro no `Response.End()`, quando ele monta o primeiro Pdf e chega no `Response.End` ele simplesmente para a execução e faz o download.

Gostaria que ele continuasse a montagem de mais documentos e após a conclusão, fizesse o download de todos os outros.

Segue o código :

```
   // Definição da Margem do PDF
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, -20f, -20f, 5f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);

    pdfDoc.Open();
    string htmlDisplayText = WBarCode(SEQ_NUM.Text);
    StringReader se = new StringReader(htmlDisplayText);
     // criação do QRcode
    var paramQR = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();
    paramQR.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, 
    CharacterSetECI.GetCharacterSetECIByName("UTF-8"));
    BarcodeQRCode qrCodigo = new BarcodeQRCode(SEQ_NUM.Text, 82, 82,       
    paramQR);
    iTextSharp.text.Image imgQRCode = qrCodigo.GetImage();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);

    .
    .
    .
    pdfDoc.Add(table);
    //exibição da imagem do código de barras.
    obj.Parse(se);

    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Clear();
    // * Especifica o MIMETYPE

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
    filename="Nome_do_arquivo.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    // * Libera o documento
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer());

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.OutputStream.Close();

    // Fechamento do arquivo
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível enviar múltiplos arquivos via HTTP Request/Response. Você vai precisar fazer várias requisições ou "empacotar" seus arquivos em `.zip`, `.rar`, `.cab` e etc.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu poderia fazer várias requisições sem que parasse no "Response.End()" ?